# Excel conversion of US date (text) to european date (date)

Tags: string, excel, date

I am pasting data from a US webpage into an excel sheet. A European Excel cannot understand American dates.... so I paste it as Text.

The difference between US and European dates is that the day and month is in a different order. How do I get from a "US text date" to real date that "European" Excel can understand? Reading it as dates doesn't work, so YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY() will not work on the native textstring. Some string conversion must be done first.

The third column is just to to show the problem. That is the result af MONTH function called on text in column "A". It is taking the day for the month and therefore throws an error when reaching the 13th of September.

```
TEXT (from US web)       EU date (real date)            MONTH(A1)
9/8/10 10:03 PM          8. Sep 2010                    8
9/9/10 10:03 PM          9. Sep 2010                    9
9/10/10 10:03 PM         10. Sep 2010                   10
9/11/10 10:03 PM         11. Sep 2010                   11
9/12/10 9:40 PM          12. Sep 2010                   12
9/13/10 9:40 PM          13. Sep 2010                   ERROR
9/14/10 9:40 PM          14. Sep 2010                   ERROR
9/15/10 9:28 PM          15. Sep 2010                   ERROR
```

If there is no "conversion function" then a solution could be to split m/d/yy to three columns and create a date from that. If so I need some help with splitting the text into a day, month and  year.

UPDATE with answer.... Lazarus came up with one that works. First, split the text in column A into Year, month and day. Then combine them eg. using the DATE function

- Year: `MID(A2,FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1)+1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1)-1)`
- Month: `MID(A2,1,FIND("/",A2,1)-1)`
- Day: `MID(A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1,FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1)-FIND("/",A2,1)-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your first date is in Cell A2, then the following will convert from the US to the European structure.

```
=DATE("2000"+MID(A2,FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1)+1,
 FIND(" ",A2,1)-FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1)-1),
 MID(A2,1,FIND("/",A2,1)-1),MID(A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1, 
 FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2,1)+1)-FIND("/",A2,1)-1))
```

Comment: Perfect! Only had to translate to my European version. Other function names and I have to use semicolon ; instead of commas ,

Comment: A pleasure, I find it surprising that as Excel is seen as more of a data tool these days that it doesn't have a better (or more obvious) method for handling certain data types.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Excel's DATEVALUE() function to convert the text string to an actual Excel date value

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Then you can number-format-mask this as you need

Comment: Thanks for the input on the dateavalue function. But the rest of the answer will not nork in this case since there either will be one OR two integers for both day and month (year always 2). And using the RIGHT function will pick characters from the time that is written in same cell after the date. Still thanks a lot. I could have used it for inspiration to the "final" line if not Lazarus all ready had posted a bullet proof conversion line ;-) BR. Anders

Answer (score 0):

```
=((MID(A1,(SEARCH("/",A1,1)+1),((SEARCH(RIGHT(A1,4),A1,1)-1)-(SEARCH("/",A1,1)+1))))&"/"&LEFT(A1,(SEARCH("/",A1,1)-1))&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4))+0
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use text to columns to split the initial USA value into three components. Then you should get Day, month, year out of the work done. With these three components present re-assemble utilising Concatenate and use the Rept() command to add the leading zeroes back in where required.